How to Handle Internationalisation and store region while statically generating all the pages in nextjs 14
Am building out a small e-commerce website that has like 4-10 products. which also has multiple language support, and multiple regional support.
├── api
│   ├── revalidate
│   │   └── route.ts
│   └── settings
│       └── set-cookie
│           └── route.ts
├── favicon.ico
└── [locale]
    ├── globals.css
    ├── layout.tsx
    ├── (pages)
    │   ├── layout.tsx
    │   ├── products
    │   │   ├── page.tsx
    │   │   └── [productId]
    │   │       └── page.tsx
    │   ├── project
    │   │   └── [level]
    │   │       ├── layout.tsx
    │   │       ├── page.tsx
    │   │       └── [projectId]
    │   │           ├── _data.tsx
    │   │           └── page.tsx
    │   └── projects
    │       ├── [level]
    │       │   ├── layout.tsx
    │       │   ├── page.tsx
    │       │   └── [pagination]
    │       │       └── page.tsx
    │       └── _page.tsx
    └── page.tsx


This is my current folder structure, I have used the cookies, but using cookies will.. make the product and and home page dynamic since both the pages need the cookie's
also am using cookies on layout so that I assume all the page's might goes to dynamic even tho its static.
Soo is there anyway to obtain the static support for these kind of problems. even tho its not vastly dynamic but just for 2 store localization strings.
Also I could also do another dynamic page [region] and make for both. soo Currently there are like 68 pages statically generated.
and doing this might multiply right like......... 128 infact. so my other question would be. how much static gen pages can be done in Vercel free-tier ?
or is the pricing much more complex ?
